# nginx: [emerg] "include" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

My page has a lot a redirects. I placed them all in a file `redirects.conf` and included it:

```
server {
   ...
   include redirects.conf;
}
```

The `redirects.conf` file looks like this:

```
rewrite  ^/[Gg]ewinnspiel/?$  https://www.facebook.com/Somepage.de?ref=ts permanent;
rewrite  ^/[Gg]ewinnspiel-[Oo]stern$  https://www.Somepage.de/ewinnspiele/Ostern permanent;
rewrite  ^/[Ff]euerwehr$  https://www.Somepage.de/feuerwehr.pdf permanent;
```

That works fine.

Now, I would like to split this file again. But if I place an `include part1.conf;` in my redirects.conf file I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] "include" directive is not allowed here
```

Documentation tells me include is allowed anywhere:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include

Is this no possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you want to include them.

Comment: So you have an include in an included file?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for the feedback. I added more context.